# Table on HTML page takes much more width than div with using <viewport "width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">

Tags: html, viewport

I’m making a simple **HTML page** with text and table and I want it to be responsive. So I used `<viewport “width = device-width initial-scale = 1”>` but my page looks like this:
[image]

But I need it to look like this:

[image]

I already tried to remove **table** from page and everything looked good. But with the **table** it looks not properly. How can I make it to look properly without **BootStrap**?

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Name of title</title>

  <style>
    table {
      border: solid 1px;
      border-spacing: 0
    }
    
    td {
      border: solid 1px;
      padding: 0.5em
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Poker Tutorial</h1>
  <div>
    <p>No-Limit Texas Hold'em is often said to be a game that takes only a minute to learn, but a lifetime to master.</p>
    <p>While the game can involve extremely complicated strategies - especially by the pros at the top level of the game, the fundamentals are fairly simple to learn. After watching this short video you should be able to take a seat at a play money table
      and know what your options are when it is your turn to act. </p>
  </div>
  <h2>Standard poker combinations</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Combination</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Column3</td>
      <td>Column4</td>
      <td>Column5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Royal Flush</td>
      <td>A&hearts;K&hearts;Q&hearts;J&hearts;10&hearts;</td>
      <td>42112</td>
      <td>21123</td>
      <td>123123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Straight Flush</td>
      <td>K&hearts;Q&hearts;J&hearts;10&hearts;9&hearts;</td>
      <td>3216</td>
      <td>4234</td>
      <td>123123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Full House (3+2)</td>
      <td>A&hearts;A&spades;A&diams;8&hearts;8&spades;</td>
      <td>374214</td>
      <td>23423423</td>
      <td>123123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Flush (one suit)</td>
      <td>K&hearts;Q&hearts;J&hearts;8&hearts;7&hearts;</td>
      <td>512108</td>
      <td>24234</td>
      <td>123123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Straight (row)</td>
      <td>K&hearts;Q&spades;J&diams;10&clubs;9&hearts;</td>
      <td>1022100</td>
      <td>24234234</td>
      <td>123123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Triple (3 of a kind)</td>
      <td>A&hearts;A&spades;A&diams;K&hearts;2&clubs;</td>
      <td>5491221</td>
      <td>423423</td>
      <td>123123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Two pairs</td>
      <td>K&hearts;K&spades;8&diams;8&hearts;2&clubs;</td>
      <td>123552</td>
      <td>42125</td>
      <td>123123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pair</td>
      <td>K&hearts;K&spades;8&diams;3&hearts;2&clubs;</td>
      <td>1098240</td>
      <td>422133</td>
      <td>123123123</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please can you add your code, we cannot help without seeing that first.

Comment: @DKyleo, I'm sorry, I posted it now

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Name of title</title>

  <style>
    table {
      border: solid 1px;
      border-spacing: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td {
      border: solid 1px;
      padding: 0.5em
    }
    
    #wrapper {
      max-width: 100%;
    } //CHANGE THIS TO IF NEEDED.
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper"> //
    <-- ADD THIS WRAPPER TO INCLUDE ALL ITEMS <h1>Poker Tutorial</h1>
      <div>
        <p>No-Limit Texas Hold'em is often said to be a game that takes only a minute to learn, but a lifetime to master.</p>
        <p>While the game can involve extremely complicated strategies - especially by the pros at the top level of the game, the fundamentals are fairly simple to learn. After watching this short video you should be able to take a seat at a play money table
          and know what your options are when it is your turn to act. </p>
      </div>
      <h2>Standard poker combinations</h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Combination</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Column3</td>
          <td>Column4</td>
          <td>Column5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Royal Flush</td>
          <td>A&hearts;K&hearts;Q&hearts;J&hearts;10&hearts;</td>
          <td>42112</td>
          <td>21123</td>
          <td>123123123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Straight Flush</td>
          <td>K&hearts;Q&hearts;J&hearts;10&hearts;9&hearts;</td>
          <td>3216</td>
          <td>4234</td>
          <td>123123123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Full House (3+2)</td>
          <td>A&hearts;A&spades;A&diams;8&hearts;8&spades;</td>
          <td>374214</td>
          <td>23423423</td>
          <td>123123123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Flush (one suit)</td>
          <td>K&hearts;Q&hearts;J&hearts;8&hearts;7&hearts;</td>
          <td>512108</td>
          <td>24234</td>
          <td>123123123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Straight (row)</td>
          <td>K&hearts;Q&spades;J&diams;10&clubs;9&hearts;</td>
          <td>1022100</td>
          <td>24234234</td>
          <td>123123123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Triple (3 of a kind)</td>
          <td>A&hearts;A&spades;A&diams;K&hearts;2&clubs;</td>
          <td>5491221</td>
          <td>423423</td>
          <td>123123123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Two pairs</td>
          <td>K&hearts;K&spades;8&diams;8&hearts;2&clubs;</td>
          <td>123552</td>
          <td>42125</td>
          <td>123123123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Pair</td>
          <td>K&hearts;K&spades;8&diams;3&hearts;2&clubs;</td>
          <td>1098240</td>
          <td>422133</td>
          <td>123123123</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

  </div> //
  <-- CLOSE THE WRAPPER TAG BY DOING THIS </body>

</html>
```

Here is my edited version of your code.

```
1.) I added a div using the id wrapper, just above the first <h1>.
2.) Add the closing tag after the table.
3.) Set properties to the ID inside the <style> element. I added max-width: 100% because it will resize depending on the screen.
```

Let me know if it works like you asked for, otherwise I'll try something else. :) Good luck mate.

Comment: Why don't you have a CSS file? Any reason for that? :)

Comment: No, I just have to stylish a couple things, that’s why I didn’t create a separate CSS file. It also is going to be in Android App and that’s more convenient:)

Comment: So, the header, div and div are going to be placed from the left side, all the way to the right side?  Correct?

Comment: https://codepen.io/lolprezy/pen/Layavo

When adding the width: 100%, I'm getting the result you're seeking for. So I guess it's something else that's wrong.

Comment: yes, from left side all the way to the right
But actually when I tried it on my phone that's doesn't work:(

Comment: and you know, when i put for example <meta name="viewport" content="width=500 initial-scale=1.0"/> everything is good

Comment: I’m on my phone, so can’t really see so much. But try using the @media property. And if that dosen’t work. Try adding ”!important” after the width:100%

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/92ue0od   thats the result on an iphone device. so you wnt the text to be moved or what? :)

Comment: No, I just want the text to have the same width as table:)

Comment: Ohhhhhh! I totally missunderstood that. I’m home in 15 min, than i’ll help you :)

Comment: No, unfortunately that didn't help me(
But I tried also to make the font-size of table smaller, and now everything is good, but actually table is litlle bit small :) Maybe there is another way to do it with no changing table to smaller size?